# Is there an UIViewController Event that satisfies this properties:

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

It's called only once, like viewDidLoad

It's called right before viewWillAppear. So it's called after the UIViewController navigationController is no longer empty.

Basically I want to set things up programatically stuffs for UIViewController. However, I want navigationController property to already exist. Also I want the whole thing to be called only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super-familiar with view lifecycles in iOS but if by some chance there is not a method that fits your description and you *really do* need to have such an event, you could always use a call back combined with a property, ie

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
if (!self.specialMethodHasBeenCalled) { [self doSpecialMethod]; }
 // other viewWillAppear stuff to do every time
}

- (void)specialMethod {
// do stuff
self.specialMethodHasBeenCalled = YES;
}
```

Might need to do some more stuff for thread safety, but this is just a hacky solution.